# Connect QGIS with PyCharm

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pycharm

I don't get the concept of developing with Python in QGIS. There is a Tutorial in the QGIS docs how to setup PyCharm for developing standalone scripts or how to develop custom applications. The first won't start the app at all (?) and the second has to build up completely by yourself.

What I actually want is to run code in my running OOTB QGIS application but written in my PyCharm IDE ... is there somehow a way to "connect" PyCharm with the active QGIS App instance?

So to sum it up: I wanna replace the built in script editor from QGIS with my own IDE (PyCharm), but dont wanna develop a plugin or a standalone application.

What i tried is to open QGIS by double clicking the app and switch to my PyCharm IDE and hopefully somehow get a connection to my IDE here (after setting Paths to the QGIS Python dir). I assumed, that just including something like an "Apllication" object gives me a reference to the currrent running QGIS project .. but i think its not working like this, since the app wasn't started from my IDE. I don't wanna programm plugins, just wanna use PyCharm features instead of the built in file editor/console and run this scripts from PyCharm for my current opened project

Comment: "the second has to build up completely by yourself." in the documentation, it was just as an example with a self-build QGIS, but the workflow is the same if you use QGIS from binaries. Can you show/share what did you try ?

Comment: What i tried is to open QGIS by double clicking the app and switch to my PyCharm IDE and hopefully somehow get a connection to my IDE here (after setting Paths to the QGIS Python dir). I assumed, that just including something like an "Apllication" object gives me access to the currrent running QGIS project .. but i think its not working like this, since the app wasn't started from my IDE. I don't wanna programm plugins, just wanna use PyCharm features instrad of the built in file editor/console and run this scripts from PyCharm

Comment: Please edit your question and do not add in comments.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: I do not use PyCharm but in general you need to point your IDE to the same Python installation that includes pyqgis.  Then you need to correctly set your environment variables.  See here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#interpreter  and here:  https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#using-pyqgis-in-standalone-scripts

Comment: @GBG it's clear to me that the env has been set correctly ... but how to connect to my running instance? The script as stated will neither connect to my running application nor starting a new one from the IDE (even with showGui=true)

Comment: In Pycharm start a new script with only this command below.  What message is returned?     from qgis.core import *

Comment: The script runs, so import is working. "Finished with exit code 1" or so.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use "QGIS Plugin Builder" plug-in.
When you use it, Plugin Builder creates project files for you. You can create those files where you want.
[image]

After that you can connect that files to QGIS plug-in files with 'Link Shell Extension' as a symbolic link. https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now if you change anything in dialog.py (You can use PyCharm for that and create a project file with dialog.py) effect your plug-in after reload the plug-in in QGIS. For reload the plug-in you can use 'Plug-in Reloader'.

[image]

For more information you can watch those video series:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GccxvQ1ypbc

I am not completely sure what is the ask for but i hope it will be usefull for you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question is about how to setup PyCharm to have the API integration withing the IDE : autocompletion, API check etc. It's not about pre-generated files. Side note, I don't recommand "QGIS Plugin builder", this plugin is not maintained anymore and generating too much files IMHO.

Comment: I did have a similar question, and also there it seemed as if it was not (immediately) understand: The question is, if you can access the running QGIS project instance, e.g. accessing or setting an active layer from Pycharm. For example, in Pycharm, when you configure your python interpreter  to the path C:/ProgramFiles/QGIS 3.28.3/bin/python-qgis.bat it does recognize the qgis library and you can use it, however, you have not access to a run  QGIS desktop application, meaning all info you generally can retrieve from the running project cannot be accessed, e.g. iface.activeLayer() won't work.